# PHP code analayzer and other tools

Tags: php

I am new to PHP (worked around 7 years on ASP.NET)
We are looking for some tools for PHP which we can use to make sure code quality is good.

we are using Notepad++ as a IDE and SVN for code repository.

Answer (score 0):

I became a convert to Netbeans after using NP++ for quite some time.  It's got some cool formatting and on-the-fly code checks, as well as very thorough autosuggests and integration with version control (subversion for me)

My coworkers use Rapid PHP which is just about identical, though it has a great block highlight feature.

Separate of editors, I can say enough how great the W3 validator is for making sure the output is really good.  Often times it can help you spot missing or misplaced end tags or other minor html issues like that.  After Netbeans, firebug, and Chrome Inspector, I'd say it's one of my top used tools.